# How to get the keyboard height on multiple screens with SwiftUI and move the button

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, xcode11

The following code gets the keyboard height when the keyboard is displayed and moves the button by the keyboard height.

This movement is performed in the same way at the transition source (ContentView) and the transition destination (SecibdContentView), but the button does not move at the transition destination.

How can I make the buttons move the same on multiple screens?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var keyboard = KeyboardResponder()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("ContentView")

                Spacer()

                NavigationLink(destination: SecondContentView()) {
                    Text("Next")
                }
                .offset(x: 0, y: -keyboard.currentHeight)
            }
        }
    }
}

import SwiftUI

struct SecondContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var keyboard = KeyboardResponder()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("SubContentView")

            Spacer()

            NavigationLink(destination: ThirdContentView()) {
                Text("Next")
            }
            .offset(x: 0, y: -keyboard.currentHeight)
        }
    }
}

class KeyboardResponder: ObservableObject {
    private var _center: NotificationCenter
    @Published var currentHeight: CGFloat = 0

    init(center: NotificationCenter = .default) {
        _center = center
        _center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillShow(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        _center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillHide(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        _center.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @objc func keyBoardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            currentHeight = keyboardSize.height
        }
    }

    @objc func keyBoardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
        currentHeight = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried it on Simulator, what a workaround. It's sad to see SwiftUI does not handle this natively. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## Using ViewModifier

You can use ViewModifier of swiftui is much simpler

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct KeyboardAwareModifier: ViewModifier {
    @State private var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0

    private var keyboardHeightPublisher: AnyPublisher<CGFloat, Never> {
        Publishers.Merge(
            NotificationCenter.default
                .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)
                .compactMap { $0.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue }
                .map { $0.cgRectValue.height },
            NotificationCenter.default
                .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)
                .map { _ in CGFloat(0) }
       ).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .padding(.bottom, keyboardHeight)
            .onReceive(keyboardHeightPublisher) { self.keyboardHeight = $0 }
    }
}

extension View {
    func KeyboardAwarePadding() -> some View {
        ModifiedContent(content: self, modifier: KeyboardAwareModifier())
    }
}
```

And in your view

```
struct SomeView: View {
    @State private var someText: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            TextField("some text", text: $someText)
        }.KeyboardAwarePadding()
    }
}
```

`KeyboardAwarePadding()` will automatically add a padding in your view, It's more elegant.

Comment: Indeed very elegant solution. Tiny alteration to cope with safeAreaInsets.bottom
```
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .padding(.bottom, keyboardHeight)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(keyboardHeight==0 ? [] :.bottom)
            .onReceive(keyboardHeightPublisher) { self.keyboardHeight = $0 }
    }
```

Comment: nice solution, but how to make it work for VStack placed in scrollview as well?

Comment: For some reason, my keyboard height toggles between `69.0` (when hidden) and `336.0` (when shown), never 0.0 which is strange. Any Idea?

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander, also add an .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)

Comment: Thanks Bro We have tried a lot things and we faced issue in different Device dimensions, but this solution is working perfectly in all the devices sizes.

Answer (score 1):

#### SwiftUI + Combine

```
@Published var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0 // if one is in ViewModel: ObservableObject

private var cancellableSet: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
init() {
        
     NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIWindow.keyboardWillShowNotification)
       .map {
             guard
                 let info = $0.userInfo,
                 let keyboardFrame = info[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect
                 else { return 0 }

             return keyboardFrame.height
         }
         .assign(to: \.keyboardHeight, on: self)
         .store(in: &cancellableSet)
        
     NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIWindow.keyboardDidHideNotification)
         .map { _ in 0 }
         .assign(to: \.keyboardHeight, on: self)
         .store(in: &cancellableSet)
    }
```

Comment: im guessing this should be in a class not struct right?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a couple of things missing. There's no NavigationView, and no TextFields to make the keyboard appear. Consider updating your code.

Anyway, the problem can be solved easily by replacing: `keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` with `keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`.

**Update:**

You also need to use the same KeyboardResponder, otherwise you will creating multiple instances. Alternatively, you can put it into your Evironment.

And you forgot to include TextFields to your code, so the keyboard will show up to test it.

The following code works:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var keyboard = KeyboardResponder()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("ContentView")
                TextField("enter text", text: .constant(""))
                Spacer()

                NavigationLink(destination: SecondContentView(keyboard: keyboard)) {
                    Text("Next")
                }
                .offset(x: 0, y: -keyboard.currentHeight)
            }
        }
    }
}

import SwiftUI

struct SecondContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var keyboard: KeyboardResponder

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("SubContentView")
            TextField("enter text", text: .constant(""))
            Spacer()

            NavigationLink(destination: Text("ThirdContentView()")) {
                Text("Next")
            }
            .offset(x: 0, y: -keyboard.currentHeight)
        }
    }
}

class KeyboardResponder: ObservableObject {
    private var _center: NotificationCenter
    @Published var currentHeight: CGFloat = 0

    init(center: NotificationCenter = .default) {
        _center = center
        _center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillShow(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        _center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillHide(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        _center.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @objc func keyBoardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            currentHeight = keyboardSize.height
        }
    }

    @objc func keyBoardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
        currentHeight = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry.
Added NavigationView.
I changed keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey to keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey, but I couldn't confirm the movement of the button in SubContentView.

Comment: You forgot to include TextFields. I updated my answer to include a working solution.

Comment: This stops working as soon as someone starts typing on the keyboard