# Retrieving keyboard height when textfield editing starts in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, keyboard, swiftui, textfield, editing

So I have a class with a published variable called keyboardHeight that is used to retrieve the value of the keyboardHeight:

```
import UIKit

class KeyboardHeightHelper: ObservableObject {
@Published var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0

init() {
    self.listenForKeyboardNotifications()
}

private func listenForKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification,
                                           object: nil,
                                           queue: .main) { (notification) in
                                            guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
                                                let keyboardRect = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect else { return }
                                            
                                            self.keyboardHeight = keyboardRect.height
    }
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardDidHideNotification,
                                           object: nil,
                                           queue: .main) { (notification) in
                                            self.keyboardHeight = 0
    }
}

}
```

Then, in ContentView I just have a TextField that should print the keyboard height when you start/stop editing the field:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var textFieldText = ""
    @ObservedObject var keyboardHeightHelper = KeyboardHeightHelper()
    var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField("Text field",
                  text: $textFieldText, onEditingChanged: { _ in print("the keyboard height is \(self.keyboardHeightHelper.keyboardHeight)") })
        
    }

   }
}
```

The problem I have is this: When I am not editing the textfield and then click it, it prints the keyboard height is 0.0 (I guess this is because it grabs the keyboardHeight value before it presents the keyboard, so at the time the height is 0.0 as the keyboard isn't seen). When I press return and the keyboard is dismissed, the height of the keyboard (for the iPhone 8 simulator) is printed as the correct value of 260.0. My question is how do I access the value of the keyboard when I start editing?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/59098816/10093134

Comment: @Subha_26 Well I don't really want padding--I just need to access the CGFloat value and it seems like that question just adds padding, and if I'm being honest that code is beyond me so I'm sorry if you actually can correctly access the CGFloat value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.onEditingChanged` is not appropriate place to read keyboard height, because you receive this callback right in the moment of click in TextField, so there is no keyboard yet shown (and, so, no notification received).

Instead you can listen explicitly for your `keyboardHeight` property publisher and be notified exactly when it is changed (what is performed on keyboard notifications synchronously, so in time)

Here is a solution (tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14)

```
VStack {
    TextField("Text field",
              text: $textFieldText, onEditingChanged: { _ in  })
        .onReceive(keyboardHeightHelper.$keyboardHeight) { value in
            print("the keyboard height is \(value)")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. You can integrate it using just a modifier to SwiftUI view:

```
extension UIResponder {
    static var currentFirstResponder: UIResponder? {
        _currentFirstResponder = nil
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.findFirstResponder(_:)), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
        return _currentFirstResponder
    }

    private static weak var _currentFirstResponder: UIResponder?

    @objc private func findFirstResponder(_ sender: Any) {
        UIResponder._currentFirstResponder = self
    }
    
    var globalFrame: CGRect? {
        guard let view = self as? UIView else { return nil }
        return view.superview?.convert(view.frame, to: nil)
    }
}
```

```
extension Publishers {
    static var keyboardHeight: AnyPublisher<CGFloat, Never> {
        let willShow = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.keyboardWillShowNotification)
            .map { $0.keyboardHeight }
        
        let willHide = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.keyboardWillHideNotification)
            .map { _ in CGFloat(0) }
        
        return MergeMany(willShow, willHide)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

extension Notification {
    var keyboardHeight: CGFloat {
        return (userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect)?.height ?? 0
    }
}
```

```
struct KeyboardAdaptive: ViewModifier {
    @State private var bottomPadding: CGFloat = 0

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            content
                .padding(.bottom, self.bottomPadding)
                .onReceive(Publishers.keyboardHeight) { keyboardHeight in
                    let keyboardTop = geometry.frame(in: .global).height - keyboardHeight
                    let focusedTextInputBottom = UIResponder.currentFirstResponder?.globalFrame?.maxY ?? 0
                    self.bottomPadding = max(0, focusedTextInputBottom - keyboardTop - geometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
            }
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.16))
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func keyboardAdaptive() -> some View {
        ModifiedContent(content: self, modifier: KeyboardAdaptive())
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            
            TextField("Enter something", text: $text)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        }
        .padding()
        .keyboardAdaptive()//note this
    }
}
```

Credits to multiple online sources.

Comment: Hi Subha, I don't really want to add padding like I said before--I just want to be able to access the value of keyboardHeight not really add padding.